# Filter PullRequest by assignee or tags on Github API

Tags: curl, github-api

there!

I'm using Github API to get the list of pull requests on a repo;

My auth token is valid and I'm receiving a valid JSON response from Github

```
curl -H "Authorization: token MY_AUTH_TOKEN" https://api.github.com/repos/my_org/their_repo/pulls
```

I'm following their docs on: https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/

**But I'm also interested in filter the pull requests by the user login just like Github does when we are using it on the browser**

Example: https://github.com/rails/rails/pulls/assigned/dhh

I've tried both URLs:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/my_org/their_repo/pulls/assigned/_login_
```

and

```
https://api.github.com/repos/my_org/their_repo/pulls?assigned=_login_
```

But I couldn't find how to filter the list using the assignee or tags.

I found in the docs just the params: state, head, base, sort and direction.

**How to filter the pull request using this options (tags or assignees)?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using Github API v3

You can use Github [Search issues API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues) :

```bash
curl -s "https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=is:open%20is:pr%20assignee:dhh%20repo:rails/rails"
```

or using `--data-urlencode` :

```bash
curl -s -G "https://api.github.com/search/issues" \
     --data-urlencode "q=is:open is:pr assignee:dhh repo:rails/rails" | \
     jq '.'
```

#### Using Github GraphQL API v4

You can use the search query like this :

```graphql
{
  search(query: "is:open is:pr assignee:dhh repo:rails/rails", type: ISSUE, first: 100) {
    issueCount
    edges {
      node {
        ... on PullRequest {
          number
          createdAt
          title
          headRef {
            name
            repository {
              nameWithOwner
            }
          }
          body
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20search(query%3A%20%22is%3Aopen%20is%3Apr%20assignee%3Adhh%20repo%3Arails%2Frails%22%2C%20type%3A%20ISSUE%2C%20first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20issueCount%0A%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20PullRequest%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20number%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20createdAt%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20headRef%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20repository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nameWithOwner%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20body%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) & [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

```bash
curl -s -H "Authorization: bearer YOUR_TOKEN" -d '
{
    "query": "query { search(query: \"is:open is:pr assignee:dhh repo:rails/rails\", type: ISSUE, first: 100) { issueCount edges { node { ... on PullRequest { number createdAt title headRef { name repository { nameWithOwner } } body } } } } }"
}
' https://api.github.com/graphql | jq '.'
```

Comment: Thanks @Bertrand I'll give it a try!

Comment: It worked, thanks; though the response from search issues does not include the branch(ref) names.

Comment: @AndreDurao I've updated with GraphQL API so you can select which specific field you want from the PR